# I can't add view to .Net Core MVC Project at Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: .net, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac to build a .net core MVC project, but I can't create views. How can I create a `View` from a `Controller`, and how can I use a layout for this view?

[image: HomeController]

Answer (score 2):

It actually isn't that bad - you can go to the Views directory and find the folder for the controller you want the view for. Right-click on the controller directory and use the "add scaffold" option to create a view with templated code.

See below.

Add Scaffolded View in Visual Studio for Mac:
[image: Add Scaffolded View in Visual Studio for Mac]

Answer (score 1):

On ASP.Net Core not exist that function so you need to create views "by hand"

For more i reccomend to read from official docs [Adding a view to an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view)

Comment: I tried it but "Visual Studio for Mac" doesn't contain View Page.

Comment: So create empty file, name it `*.cshtml` and then use like "normal" view page